# Disable physical left click on touchpad but keeping tap

Tags: touchpad, libinput, tap-to-click

I need to disable the physical clicking on the left touchpad as my touchpad is a bit broken and get stuck specifically on the left side. I think libinput should do the work but I am unable to find the correct function. I end up deactivating the whole touchpad altogether.

Answer (score 0):

first run;

```
xinput
```

the output looks like this;

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
```

in my case the touchpad ID is 18 (check the correct ID for yours) and;

```
xinput get-button-map 18
```

you will get this;

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

where 1 is the left click
now disable it by set 0 as new variable;

```
xinput set-button-map 18 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

hope this help you.

Comment: hi there, thanks but that would disable the left button and prevent me to even use tap to click. do you know of any other way that would still allow me to use tap to click but disable the physical pressing of the left button?

Comment: the above example tested on my touchpad. i stil tap on it and left click disabled. can you post the output of your `xinput get-button-map ID` please?

Comment: the result of the command is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. when I did your xinput set-button-map 12 0 2 3 4 5 6 7, I confirm I can no longer use tap-to-click